# This package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, metro-bundler

Trying to run a react-native project that has [x-resources](https://github.com/pablohpsilva/x-resources) package as dependency, installed the dependencies using yarn, but when i try to run the project i get this error at run time

```
bundling failed: Error: While trying to resolve module `x-resources` from file `/***/index.js`, the package `/***/node_modules/x-resources/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/***/node_modules/x-resources/dist/index.js`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

 *  /***/node_modules/x-resources/dist/index.js(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
 * /***/node_modules/x-resources/dist/index.js/index(.native|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)

    at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/***/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:65:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/***/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:282:16)
    at Object.resolve (/***/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:267:42)
    at /***/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:426:31
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/***/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:423:18)
    at /***/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:275:33
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (/***/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:87:24)
    at _next (/***/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:107:9)
```

There is no **/dist** folder in this package and i can't understand why it's looking for index.js inside it, i don't know if it's a metro related issue or it's specific to this package, i've tried closing the running js server multiple times but no luck.

- react: 16.9.0
- react-native: 0.61.4
- x-resources: 1.1.2
- axios: 0.19.0

Comment: Are you able to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to mismatched `node_modules` & `Pods`. I saw a similar error when updating deps within a yarn workspaces project and I solved this by purging my dependencies, *all* my dependencies, including within sub-packages.

```bash
rm -rf yarn.lock ./node_modules ./ios/Pods ./ios/Podfile.lock
rm -rf ./**/node_modules/ ./**/iods/Pods ./**/ios/Podfile.lock
```

Removing the lockfiles isn't strictly required, as we just want to ensure that the node_modules are in a pristine state.

Comment: Is `say done` really necessary or relevant?

Comment: No, removed it.

Comment: This answer is -->legit<--